# Getting all email addresses from table

Tags: php

The code below shows one email address as a output but I want to get a list of all 
email addresses (seperated by comma) of customer table. How can I get that?

```
<?php

    $SQLstring = "SELECT email FROM customers";
    $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
                   or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.</p>" .
                          "<p> Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect) . ":" . mysqli_error                 ($DBConnect))."</p>";

    $NumRows = mysqli_num_rows($QueryResult);
    if ($NumRows == 0)
    {
        echo "<p>No email found.</p>";
    }

    else
    {
        for($i = 1; $i <= $NumRows; $i++)

        {
            $Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult);
            $email = stripslashes($Row[0]);
            echo $email;
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `mysqli` **not** `mysql` you're using so things work a little differently...

Assuming you've created your mysqli connection with something like `$DBConnect = new msqli( ... );`

It's probably better to store the result before you manipulate it; try something like:

```
$success = $DBConnect->real_query($SQLstring);
if($success) {
  $result = $DBConnect->store_result();
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['email'] . "<br />\n"; //for debugging purposes
  }
}

$result->free();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$email = stripslashes($Row[0]);
```

To:

```
$email = stripslashes($Row[$i]);
```

And you should be set

Comment: still getting just one email address

Answer (score 1):

The PHP docs say that mysqli_num_rows may not return the correct number of rows until you've retrieved all rows, so perhaps, instead of using a row count, just keep fetching rows until you run out:

```
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult))
{
   $email = stripslashes($Row[0]);
   echo $email;
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want to store the emails in an array rather than just echoing them, simply change it to this:

```
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult))
{
   $email[] = stripslashes($Row[0]);
}
```

Now $email will be an array containing all of the emails.

Comment: but i want all email addresses seperated by comma..so how can i store all values in array

Comment: By storing $email instead of echoing it.

Comment: while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult))
{
   $email[] = stripslashes($Row[0]);
}

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_fetch_assoc in while loop

$NumRows = mysqli_num_rows($QueryResult);

```
if ($NumRows == 0)
      {
     echo "<p>No email found.</p>";             
      }

   else 
      {
       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)){

                  $email = stripslashes($row['email']);
                          echo $email;
             }
      }
```